# How to save a button's position and settings?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to create an options menu for a game, where there are 2 buttons. One button is to disable all music, and the other is to disable all sound effects. When the button is clicked, it disappears with the .visible = false; code. The new button underneath is shown. When a person exits the game, I want the game to remember the settings, and which button is hidden.

Example: A person plays the game, but goes to options menu to disable sound. Sound is disabled, and the off button underneath is shown. The player exits the options menu, then exits the game. The player opens the game back up. The sound should still be disabled, and if the player goes to the options menu, the on button should still be invisible and the off button should be visible.

Could you please help me on how I can create this sort of system?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ['SharedObject'](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) class to store your data locally, then read it again on Startup.
See these examples as a start: [example1](http://snipplr.com/view/11917/), [example2](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/12/28/understanding-as3-shared-objects/)

Comment: I know how to use shared object for dynamic text fields, but I am having trouble with movie clips..how do I do them for movie clips? Like my movie clip symbol instance is "optionsmenu_mc" when clicked it disappears. If the user exits out, the movie clip should still be invisible. I am really new at as3, and I am having trouble creating this